# Unable to get past a loop in python using libmproxy

Tags: python, webdriver

I'm using [libmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/library.html) to capture http traffic. I would like to use web driver to load a web page while the proxy is running. The proxy code is working great but I am unable to launch the page. I assume the script is becoming stuck in a loop at m.run(). How can I move to the web driver code while the proxy is running?

```
import unittest
import sys
from libmproxy import proxy, dump, cmdline
from libmproxy.version import VERSION
from optparse import OptionParser
from selenium import webdriver


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        parser = OptionParser(
                    usage = "%prog [options] [filter]",
                    version="%%prog %s"%VERSION,
                )
        cmdline.common_options(parser)
        parser.add_option(
            "--keepserving",
            action="store_true", dest="keepserving", default=False,
            help="Continue serving after client playback or file read. We exit by default."
        )

        options, args = parser.parse_args()

        if options.quiet:
            options.verbose = 0

        proxyconfig = proxy.process_proxy_options(parser, options)
        if options.no_server:
            server = proxy.DummyServer(proxyconfig)
        else:
            try:
                server = proxy.ProxyServer(proxyconfig, options.port, options.addr)
            except proxy.ProxyServerError, v:
                print >> sys.stderr, "mitmdump:", v.args[0]
                sys.exit(1)


        try:
            dumpopts = dump.Options(**cmdline.get_common_options(options))
        except cmdline.OptionException, v:
            parser.error(v.message)
        dumpopts.keepserving = options.keepserving

        if args:
            filt = " ".join(args)
        else:
            filt = None


        try:
            PROXY_HOST = "localhost"
            PROXY_PORT = 8080


            #driver.get("http://msn.com")
            #f = open('/Users/cnave/Documents/capture/dump.txt', 'w')
            #sys.stdout('/Users/cnave/Documents/capture/dump.txt', 'w')
            #open('/Users/cnave/Documents/capture/dump.txt', 'w')
            m = dump.DumpMaster(server, dumpopts, filt) 
            m.run()
            #sys.stdout('/Users/cnave/Documents/capture/dump')
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
            # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
            fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
            fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
            fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)
            fp.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "") # set this value as desired
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
            driver.get('http://google.com')


        except dump.DumpError, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, "mitmdump:", e
            sys.exit(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.dm = dump.DumpMaster(server, dumpopts, filt) 

// run the MITM proxy in a background thread

thread.start_new_thread(self.dm.run,())

// and you maybe need to shutdown the proxy in tearDown() 

self.dm.shutdown()
```